# Why is my tripssincemaintenence output 1 instead of 99 in Python classes?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using Python 3. Here is what my class and inheritance class looks like:

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self,Make,Model,Year,Weight,TripsSinceMaintenance = 0,NeedsMaintenance = False):
        self.make = Make
        self.model = Model
        self.year = Year
        self.weight = Weight
        self.needsmaintenance = NeedsMaintenance
        self.tripssincemaintenance = TripsSinceMaintenance
    def repair(self):
        self.needsmaintenance = True
        self.tripssincemaintenance = 0

class Cars(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self,Make,Model,Year,Weight,TripsSinceMaintenance = 0,NeedsMaintenance = False,isdriving = False):
        Vehicle.__init__(self,Make,Model,Year,Weight,TripsSinceMaintenance = 0,NeedsMaintenance = False)
        self.isDriving = isdriving
    def Drive(self):
        self.isDriving = True
        
    def Stop(self):
        self.isDriving = False
        self.tripssincemaintenance += 1
        if self.tripssincemaintenance == 100:
            self.needsmaintenance = True
```

This is where I make use of the class:

```
    Car2 = Cars("Mercedes","G-Wagon","2016","2000", 98,False)
    Car2.Drive()
    Car2.Stop()
    print(Car2.year)
    print(Car2.model)
    print(Car2.make)
    print(Car2.isDriving)
    print(Car2.needsmaintenance)
    print(Car2.tripssincemaintenance)
    print(Car2.weight)
```

The problem is that when self.tripssincemaintenance is printed, it shows 1 instead of 99. Why is that? TIA

Comment: You are setting `0` to `TripsSinceMaintenance` while initializing super class's constructor. (line 17)